# Binding in Xcode 8 and Swift 3: Target never gets called and argument is passed as uninitialized

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, binding, target-action

Here's 2 binding issues I'd like to share with you, related to *selector* name and *parameters* when configured in **IB**.

I have `CoreData` objets retrieved through an `ArrayController` and populated in a `NSTableView`. All the binding is made through **Interface Builder**. Each row contains a button that should check an url (one of the properties of the entity).

**1. To make the button fire, I first tried to bind it this way:**

For the target:

- Bind to: File's owner (in this case, a `ViewController`)
- Model Key Path: `self`
- Selector Name: `revealInFinder:`

For the argument:

- Bind to: `Table Cell View`
- Model Key Path: **ObjectValue**
- Selector Name: `revealInFinder: (<automatically set>)`

When I click the button, the function `revealInFinder(object: NSManagedObject)` that I wrote in the `ViewController` is simply never called: I tried with or without argument, with or without a colon, nothing happens: no breakpoint triggered, no message in the console.
I can put random chars in the selector name, I don't even get a

> "unrecognized selector name"!

... Same thing if I change the name of the function in the `ViewController`, or simply remove it: Nothing happens and no errors in console (of course, I've checked: the **owner of the File** is set to be the `ViewController`, but the view wouldn't show up anyway).

As the binding are made in IB and not in code, it's difficult to trace and debug my mistakes (I also put -NSBindingDebugLogLevel 1 to the “Arguments to be passed at launch”, as recommended here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/Troubleshooting.html). But how am I supposed to handle something that is apparently a "non-event"??
Sure I'm missing something here but what?

2-I've decided to bind the button in a different way:

For the target: (without argument at first)

- Bind to: Table Cell View
- Model Key Path: ObjectValue (so the Core Data's entity, right?)
- Selector Name: revealInFinder:

This works, as I created `NSManagedbject` subclasses for my entities, and wrote extensions for them.
The problem occurs when I add an argument, as I need to get the managedObjectContext to do some fetching inside the function:

For the argument:

- Bind to: File's owner
- Model Key Path: self.managedContext (the moc is set in the viewController)

After a bunch of "unrecognized selector sent" messages, I managed to write this function (not really sure why it's only called with the "_"):

```
func revealInFinder(_ managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext)
```

but the passed argument remains `0x00000000... (<uninitialized> in the console)`.
I changed the Model Key Path by removing the **self.**, and then bound it to the `managedObjectContext` of the `ArrayController` instead):

- Bind to: Array Controller
- Controller Key: ArrangedObjects
- Model Key Path: managedObjectContext

The moc still remains uninitialized.

- Why is my first try not triggering any action?
- Why the argument is uninitialized in the second try (not even **"nil"**)?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I had to answer or comment: in fact, the managedObjectContext I was trying to pass as an argument... is a property of the receiver (a managedObject always have a context!). So no argument needed. Yep, sometimes you don't think too hard, you just think wrong! ;-) But anyway, I believe both questions still hold...

Comment: Bind to the delegate of the table view.

Comment: @Willeke: Hi, could you be more specific, please? What should I bind to the delegate? Case 1? case 2? For the target? the argument? Thanks

Comment: Each cell view is loaded from the nib and loses the bindings outside the cell view. Only objects inside the cell view and the owner in `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` stay connected. The owner is usually the delegate.